# Powershell Color Schemes?

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a place where I can find Powershell Color Schemes that people have already built? Something like https://github.com/lysyi3m/osx-terminal-themes, but for Windows Powershell instead of OSX.

I did find this one: https://github.com/Segaso/MonokaiTheme, but I'm confused as to where I find this "Tools". When I right click on the top of any PowerShell window, all I see is this:

[image]

And this is all I see under properties:

[image]

Comment: In case you're using Visual Studio Code terminal, you can try something like this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yasht.terminal-all-in-one Pretty handy, though a general solution.

Comment: As a long term Linux user, my eyes hurt when using the default Powershell color scheme. Whoever designed Powershell has poor aesthetic sense.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Microsoft itself released last year [Windows Console Colortool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/08/11/introducing-the-windows-console-colortool/)

It works with/modifes the palette of any console app (cmd/Powershell/WSL-bash).

The colortool will work with any .itermcolors scheme.

[download from github](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/main/src/tools/ColorTool)

[image]

Comment: Works well for CMD. Not so much for Powershell... it makes the background purple.

Comment: Only works for Powershell current session when you use the -b option.

Comment: Issues with PowerShell redefining color table entries #5,#6 are discussed in this blog referencing the [new terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/new-experimental-console-features/)

Comment: They keep on updating this tool, but they never link to the executable. Very annoying. Any idea where to find it?

Answer (score 23):

Its easy. You can run these commands in powershell. This is a custom made color scheme.

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = ($bckgrnd = 'Black')
$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'White'
$Host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = 'DarkRed'
$Host.PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.WarningForegroundColor = 'Yellow'
$Host.PrivateData.WarningBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.DebugForegroundColor = 'Yellow'
$Host.PrivateData.DebugBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = 'Green'
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.ProgressForegroundColor = 'Blue'
$Host.PrivateData.ProgressBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
Clear-Host
```

If you want to have your own scheme you can choose colors as you wish.

To get the list of the colors. Run below command.

```
get-help write-host
```

You will get all colors available for powershell.

Comment: The slick "assign and set" move didn't work for me. If I resized the window, and even in the prompts, the `RawUI` background value didn't take. I had to run `$bckgrnd = 'Black'` on its own line and then `$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = $bckgrnd` to the color to take. But now I need to add that so that it's invoked each time I open Powershell like a `.bashrc` or `autoexec.bat`. How do I do that? **Update:** [This page seems to show how to add to your profile](https://beebom.com/how-change-powershell-color-scheme-windows-10/).

Answer (score 3):

You will find this in ISE Powershell

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use this for the color scheme.it has `solarized-dark` theme. Make sure you backup your current preset with
 `concfg export console-backup.json` once you have installed `scoop` and `concfg`. For more use this link https://github.com/lukesampson/concfg

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for an alternative to the default Blue and solarized-dark looks like a great scheme. Shame it doesn't keep cmd as default but that's okay

Answer (score 1):

Tagging on to the response by @user6811411, you could also use the entire Windows Terminal app, which integrates the colour tool and is available from the [Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701). In the app's settings, you can change the colour scheme quite easily.

The colour will only be changed for PowerShell sessions started from within the app, but I find it quite useful to organize all my terminals in one window, so that this was not a big downside for me.  I also liked the option to define customized shells.